# how to display user name after they login by their id number?

Tags: php, html

sorry if thie is duplication question, i did try to find the answer in internet and use it.. but i still can make it done... here my problem... i want to know how to display name when login using no id? it like welcome screen for the user after they login using their no id. here my code and sorry if it messed up...
my login.php

```
<?php


$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="1234"; // Mysql password
$db_name="vronline"; // Database name
$tbl_name="user_information"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);


$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user_id='$myusername' and user_password='$mypassword'" ;
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");

 $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                        if ($row['group_id']==0){
                        header("location:../user.php");
                        }
                        elseif ($row['group_id']==1) {
                        header("location:../admin.php");
                        }
//header("location:../menu.php");
}


else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

this is my user.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:../login_main.php");
}

?>

<?php
include ('php/dbconnect.php');

$matric = $_session['myusername'];

mysql_query("SELECT name FROM user_information WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['myusername']);


?>
<html>
<head>
<title>user</title>
<link href="source/loginstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="source/kepala.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="source/content.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="source/menuBox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="source/bottomfoot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="source/accessibility_foundicons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link href="source/general_foundicons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

<script src="source/Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<!--head-->
<div class= "kepala">


<h1>
<a href="#"><span class="foundicon-smiley"></span></a> <?php $row['name'];  ?>
</h1>


</div>


<div class= "content">


<h4>content</h4>

<div class="menu">
<div class="menu_box_list">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="php/displayuseronly.php"><span class="foundicon1-person"></span> manage user<i class="manageuser"> </i><div class="clear"></div> </a></li>
                    <li><a href="userAddvehicle.php"><span> </span>vehicle manager <i class="vehicle manager"> </i><div class="clear"></div> </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class= "foundicon-page"></span> report <i class="Report"> </i><div class="clear"></div> </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class= "foundicon-settings"></span> log out<i class="settings"> </i><div class="clear"></div> </a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>


</div>
<div class = "2nd_menu">

</div>


</div>

<div class= "Bfooter">
<h4></h4>



</div>

</div>

</body>
</head>
</html
```

i cant solve around this code

> mysql_query("SELECT name FROM user_information WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['myusername']);

how i can make it appear name instead of user_id?
sorry i am not really good about this
sorry i forgot to add this
i want the user name display here

> `<a href="#"<span></span></a> <?php $row['name']; ?>`

whenever i write i cant get the name on there.. it either not display anything or error

Comment: You're using many deprecated functions, `session_register()` for one thing.

Comment: put a var to fetch the raw data from the query, then assoc the row and you will have a var with the data

Answer (score 0):

In your login.php page use this code

```
header("location:../user.php");
session_start();
$_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;
```

And try this in user.php

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
session_start();
$matric = $_session['myusername'];

$result=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM user_information WHERE user_id='$matric'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $name=$r['name'];
   echo $name;
}
}
```

Comment: i try this the name wont display on my user.php.. is there anything i need to makesure my code right?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this :

```
$qry_sel = "SELECT name FROM user_information WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['myusername'].";";
$qry_res = mysql_query($qry_sel);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_res);

echo $row['name'];
```

Comment: it show this Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\AppServ\www\web2\user.php on line 16

Comment: can you echo your query ?